# Is there a Java API for comparing Database Schemas

Tags: java, jdbc, compare, schema, rdbms

I'd like to compare if

- tables
- columns including datatypes and length/precision.
- indexes and their columns
- constraints

in two database schemas are identical.

Is there anything like this available? Maybe from one of the database migration managing tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a high level API for schema comparison I used [DatabaseMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) it's not to hard to find differences i.g to retieve all tables you can do something like this:

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
  ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, null, 
     new String[] {"TABLE"});
  System.out.println("List of tables: "); 
  while (res.next()) {
     System.out.println(
        "   "+res.getString("TABLE_CAT") 
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_SCHEM")
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_NAME")
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_TYPE")
       + ", "+res.getString("REMARKS")); 
  }
  res.close();
```

The following methods are also important for your intention:

```
getColumns(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String columnNamePattern) 
getExportedKeys(String catalog, String schema, String table)
getIndexInfo(String catalog, String schema, String table, boolean unique, boolean approximate) 
getPrimaryKeys(String catalog, String schema, String table)
```

Answer (score 3):

[SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com) provides a Java API that presents database metadata as plain-old Java objects. While there is no API to compare the database metadata objects, but SchemaCrawler produces text (text, JSON, CSV, HTML) output that is designed to be diff-ed, using standard diff tools.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Answer (score 2):

[LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/) has [database diff](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html). But I don't know if there is an API, or just the tool.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is the only Java API that deals with databases.

You'd have to connect to both, get their respective DatabaseMetaData, and compare the two.